# Observer for Admin while creating an order

Tags: module, event-observer, custom

Is it possible to have an observer while making an order in the admin panel?

I'm trying to change the 'purchased from' depending on which customer group the customer is in. So if a customer is in the wholesale group, they would be purchasing from the wholesale storeview. Obviously this can be done manually but I'm trying to cut out human error.

For example, an admin would select a customer during order creation (this triggers the event) which in turn change the store view to the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

There are main two events available for admin order in Magento 2

1. adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before
2. adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data

**1. adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before**

> app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before', $eventData);
```

**2. adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data**

> app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data', $eventData);
```

**Other admin order related events**

1. admin_sales_order_address_update

`app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddressSave.php`

2. adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_register_before

`app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/CreditmemoLoader.php`

3. sales_convert_order_to_quote

`app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php`

4. sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item

`app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php`

5. checkout_submit_all_after

`app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php`

Comment: I  want to show one custom customer attribute under account information in create order page on admin side. How can i dot that?

Comment: is there any event to capture the product info when added all the selected products?