# Get custom attribute for customer while creating order in backend magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, custom, admin-order-create

I have created a custom attribute for customer https://prnt.sc/tb68lv
The values are getting saved in the database. i have cross checked it again after opening the customer for edit and the values were present.
But when i create an order for a customer, i found this field to be blank in Account information tab. https://prnt.sc/tb6f1k
How can i get the value of this field already displayed like email and other info.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can get value like that.

> $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
>
> $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('payment_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);

Comment: In which file i need to do this?

Comment: if you want in order you can try with observer

Comment: Is there any article i can refer?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222234/observer-for-admin-while-creating-an-order