# Magento 2: which event fires before a product gets added into cart on the admin side?

Tags: admin, event-observer, products, sku, reorder

When an admin wants to reorder an item I want to check whether that item is enabled or disabled and if its disabled I want to skip that product based on its SKUs from adding into my cart. Which event fires on the admin side that can help me to adding this feature into my magento site?

Comment: These events may help you listed here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/222294/47924.  Primarily `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before`. or `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data` depending on how much data would be available for your needs.

Comment: I tried both the events, it didn't work.

Comment: please post your modules `etc/adminhtml/events.xml`